# Integration test error h2 database

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing, integration, spock

I have a grails 2.5.5 application and integration tests running in a h2 database, but the database create tables doesn´t work with domains with defaultValue mapping with 0 or 1, sample:

```
static mapping = {
        isManufacture(defaultValue: "b'0'")
}
```

Running grails test-app -integration show me this error

```
| Error 2018-08-10 14:23:40,102 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Column "B" not found; SQL statement:
create table product (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, approval_manufacturer_date timestamp, batch_validit
```

Mapping in the true or false form works fine!

```
static mapping = {
        isManufacture(defaultValue: false)
}
```

I want know, why h2 doesń´t recognized the mapping, and if exist difference between "b'0'" or false mapping domain field

Properties of my grails app

version 2.5.5
Mysql DB

Answer (score 0):

The isManufactured looks to be a type Boolean.  The default values of a Boolean would be either true or false.  I am not sure what the "b'0'" would mean?

Comment: I think that is your problem.  The Hibernate dialect should take care of the type conversion.  You do not want to have DB specific code so you can switch between different DBs.  That is one of the benefits of using Hibernate.